# error while running lighttpd in any way, such as status 255, or invalid characters

Tags: linux, lighttpd, systemctl

I've been trying to set up a lighttpd to host a website, but when I run commands like `systemctl start lighttpd` or `systemctl status lighttpd.service` I continuously get errors.

After running `systemctl start lighttpd` , I get the following:

```
Job for lighttpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

after I run `systemctl status lighttpd.service`  I get the following:

```
lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/lighttpd.service.d
             └─dietpi.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-04-23 22:27:55 BST; 9s ago
    Process: 209906 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
        CPU: 10ms

Apr 23 22:27:55 iphone systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 23 22:27:55 iphone systemd[1]: Stopped Lighttpd Daemon.
Apr 23 22:27:55 iphone systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 23 22:27:55 iphone systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 23 22:27:55 iphone systemd[1]: Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon.
```

I also ran this, `lighttpd -t -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` and I get this:

```
2023-04-23 21:47:27: configfile.c.1909) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 2 pos: 1 invalid character in variable name
2023-04-23 21:47:27: configfile.c.1967) configfile parser failed at: (
```

Ive tried reinstalling it, purging any remaining files of apache, not even Pihole works anymore as the webpage is messed up, it doesn't even load up anymore. I've tried updating everything and installing Gamin like a lot of people say, but I don't see any solutions to this problem anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2023-04-23 21:47:27: configfile.c.1909) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 2 pos: 1 invalid character in variable name`

lighttpd has told you exactly where the problem is in your config file, the first character of line 2 of /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf. lighttpd even told you the misplaced character: `(`.  Go fix it.

Comment: Checked it there seems to be nothing wrong, if I hash anything it just says the next line is wrong. i don't see anything out of the ordinary, this is where it says there's an error, server.modules = (
“mod_access”,
“mod_accesslog”,
“mod_fastcgi”,
“mod_rewrite”,
“mod_auth”

)

Comment: I am a lighttpd developer.  lighttpd is telling you and I am telling you that there is a syntax error.  If it is not in the position where the parser threw an error, look at the preceding line(s).  (stackoverflow comments do not preserve formatting, so your comment will not show a multi-line syntax error)  Check if line 1 of your lighttpd.conf is valid.  Try to understand that you have made a syntax error and the parser is trying to parse it, and failing because you made a syntax error.  The parser thinks you are trying to write a variable name when it throws the error.

Comment: Ended up being a syntax issue in that file, it just glitched out and didn't show me that the character was wrong until I switched to looking at the output from my server using HDMI, then I saw that " was this ''. Sorry, I doubted you, but you were very correct.